# Bind a textblock to static property which isn't in the VM

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, data-binding

This is my xaml code:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding MyTranslations[0].Name}"></TextBlock>
```

What I want to do is remove the 0. Instead of 0, I need to get the correct integer from a static field in a static class which is in another project but in the samo solution.

I guess it should look like something like this:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding MyTranslations[MyStaticClass.MyStaticInt].Name}"></TextBlock>
```

How do I do this?

Comment: indexers are usually constants in xaml. let's see if that can be achieved somehow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is probably some strange way to do this syntactically in xaml, but usually when I come across strange problems like this, I usually just make a calculated property in my VM.

```cs
public string MyCurrentTranslation
{
    get { return MyTranslations[MyStaticClass.MyStaticInt].Name; }
}
```

Then just bind to that property:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding MyCurrentTranslation}"/>
```

Comment: *There is probably some strange way to do this syntactically in xaml*... nope, there isn't. This suggestion is as good as it gets.