# Binding to a variable in view-model

Tags: wpf, mvvm, data-binding

This is my XAML code:

```
<ItemsControl  MinHeight="400" BorderThickness="0" ItemsSource="{Binding People}" ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource myItemsTemplateSelector}" />
```

And in the resources:

```
<UserControl.Resources>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="ItemTemplate">
            <Button CommandParameter="{Binding}" Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}, Path=DataContext.SelectSomething}" >
                <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Cars[0].Name}"></TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Cars[0].Description}"></TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
            </Button>
    </DataTemplate>

    <selectors:MySelector ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ItemTemplate}" x:Key="myItemsTemplateSelector" />

</UserControl.Resources>
```

People is an ObservableCollection in my view-model. Person is a class which has this property:

```
public IList<Cars> Cars { get; set; }
```

As you can see, I bind the textblocks to Cars[0].Name and Cars[0].Description. The problem I have is the 0. Instead of 0 it needs to be a variable which is defined in my view-model. How can I make the binding to be something like this:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Cars[variableInVM].Name}"></TextBlock>
```

Comment: there was a similar question here [Bind a textblock to static property which isn't in the VM](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24676022/bind-a-textblock-to-static-property-which-isnt-in-the-vm). I did try to see if that is possible, but seems like not at this moment. However there is an answer to wire such properties which can be useful.

Comment: you can tell us what you are trying to achieve, perhaps there is another approach for the same instead of going the indexer way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this issue by creating a new class which has these properties: Person, Cars and CurrentCars. Then, instead of binding with Cars[index], I bind with CurrentCars.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an `IMultiBindingConverter`, and then use a `MultiBinding` that binds `Cars` and `variableInVM` and uses your converter.

The converter simply returns the `variableInVM`'s element of `Cars`.

Inside that element, you would have the `DataTemplate` shown in your question, and it would use the Car passed in.